# UIScrollView's content offset being reset

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have been struggling for a long time with a problem with a UIScrollView.

I have a `UIScrollVIew` that contains a `UITextView` as a  subview. When I select the text view a keyboard pops up. I want to resize the text view to fit exactly in the available space, and also scroll the scroll view so that the text view is positioned exactly in the visible space (not hidden by the keyboard).

When the keyboard appears I call a method that calculates the appropriate size for the text view and then performs the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                 animations:^
 { 
     self.textView.frame = frame;
 }  
 ];

[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

(here frame is the appropriate frame for the text view).

Unfortunately the scroll view does not always scroll to the correct position, especially when it is already at a non zero vertical content offset when I select the text view. I know that the content offset that I'm setting it to is correct.

After a lot of testing I finally realized that what was happening was that after the animation completed, the scroll view was automatically scrolling again.

This code does work:

```
UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 
                 animations:^
 { 
     self.textView.frame = frame;
 }
 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
     [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
 }
 ];
```

but it looks strange because the scroll view scrolls to the wrong position, then to the right one.

Does anyone know how I can prevent the scroll view from changing it's content offset when the text view frame finishes its animation?

I am testing using iOS 5.0.

---

Here is a solution that I found that works. I'm still don't completely understand what's happening, possible it has something to do with the way my springs and struts are set. Basically I am shrinking the scroll view content size by the same amount that the text view shrinks.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    // Get the height of the keyboard
    CGRect kbRect = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    kbRect = [self.view convertRect:kbRect fromView:nil];
    CGSize kbSize = kbRect.size;

    // Adjust the height of the text view to fit in the visible view
    CGRect frame = self.textView.frame;
    int visibleHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    visibleHeight -= kbSize.height;
    frame.size.height = visibleHeight;

    // Get the new scroll view content size
    CGSize contentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;
    contentSize.height = contentSize.height - self.textView.frame.size.height + frame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 
                     animations:^
     { 
         self.textView.frame = frame;
         // Note that the scroll view content size needs to be reset, or the scroll view
         // may automatically scroll to a new position after the animation is complete.
         self.scrollView.contentSize = contentSize;
         [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
     }     
     ];

    // Turn off scrolling in scroll view
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    // Update the view layout
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^
     {
         self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
         [self updateViewLayout];
     }
     ];

    // Turn on scrolling in the scroll view
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

(`[self updateViewLayout]` is a method that returns the text view to the correct height, and resets the scroll view content size, as well as making sure all the other subviews are properly positioned).

Answer (score 3):

Do not adjust the frame of the text view. All you need to do is scroll the scrollview. If you scroll the scrollview animated, then the textView will slide up animated. Just do the following:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
```

If you need the scroll view to scroll at a specific rate then manually adjust the content offset in an animation block.(I haven't tested this, you may want to adjust the animation flag, or step through the content offset one pixel at a time if this doesn't work)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
             animations:^{ 
  [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
} ];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I do need to adjust the frame of my text view. I am not changing the origin, but the height of the text view frame, which is too large to fit in the available screen space once the keyboard has appeared.

Comment: If you aren't adjusting the origin of the text view frame, then you should be able to change its height and then scroll the scroll view. It sounds like you *are* adjusting the frames origin.


`CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.textView.frame.origin.x,self.textView.frame.origin.y,self.textView.frame.size.width,self.textView.frame.size.height-50.0f);
'self.textView.frame = frame;`

Comment: Yes, I am doing something similar to your code sample, which shouldn't change the origin. The problem it seems is that when the animation finishes, the scroll view automatically scrolls to a new position. So unless I wait until the animation is finished to set the contentOffset, the scroll view ends up in the wrong position.

Comment: Maybe if you could post more of your implementation I could tell you what exactly is wrong. If you don't want the scroll view to adjust its content offset don't call 

`[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];`

If you want to scroll your scrollview and adjust your frame simultaneously put them both in the animation block.

`[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f 
             animations:^{ 
  [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
self.textView.frame = frame;
} ];`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestions. That doesn't work though me though. The whole problem is that after the animation finishes, the scroll view scrolls again, automatically. I've actually found a solution. I update the scroll content size in the animation block, shrinking it by the same amount as the text view shrinks, and the automatic scrolling stops. Possibly this has something to do with the way that my springs and struts are set. I will post more of my code in the question.

Comment: Problem with using the animationBlock is the delegate method scrollViewDidScroll: does not get called correctly. Also other delegate methods of the scrollview do not fire as they should eg. scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:

Answer (score 3):

I believe I also had something similar. I wanted my horizontal UIScrollView to go back to it's original offset (0,0), and every time I animated back to it, it would be just a couple pixels off, but as soon as someone touched the scrollview, it would continue and finish the animation (almost like lag in a video game).

Due to that, I tried putting it in GCD as the main queue and it worked perfectly fine after that. Here's the code:

```
- (void)setPageZero{
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^{
                     [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
                 }
           completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
       });
}
```

What that basically does, is that it puts the animation into the main queue (kind of like a superhighway in the CPU/GPU) and it prioritizes it over other things!

Hope this helps future readers!

Comment: This doesn't work. Setting the contentOffset with animation ignores the animation block. If you want to animate in block you have to use self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);  Its basically pointless to wrap in animation block it does not work. Note: If you use animation block some delegate methods on scrollView do not get called e.g. didScroll:

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a similar problem. Basically I have a scroll view with three pages each containing a custom `UIView` class. The custom `UIView` class contains an image and a number of overlay views containing information about the image. The overlay views contain a number of `UITextView` fields.

I attach the custom views to the scroll view and then I load the image & overlays using block operations. I swipe to the right by deleting the first view, repositioning the next two views, and adding an new view to the right.

If I create the `UITextField` objects and disable scrolling as follows:

```
UITextView* view = [[UITextView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(position.x,position.y,width,height)];
view.editable = NO;  
view.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Then the scroll view gets repositioned between pages when I return from the block code. Note that I don't reposition the scroll view and on exit from the block, the scroll view is in the correct position.

However, if I comment out the code to disable scrolling

```
UITextView* view = [[UITextView alloc]
                    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(position.x,position.y,width,height)];
view.editable = NO;  
// view.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

this repositioning does not occur and the scrolling works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Complete hack: May improve the reset issue:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{        
        [self setContentOffset:self.contentOffset animated:NO];
}
```